# Gulp jshint errors

Tags: jquery, node.js, gruntjs, gulp, jshint

After looking at Grunt, I decided that I preferred Gulp as a task runner, purely because I prefer code over config. I have set up my first task to run jshint and jscsrc using defaults. I am amazed at a few things. Firstly, I am using stock jquery and bootstrap files and the amount of errors/suggestions shown in the code linting is huge. Secondly, when I run the task, my memory gets blown away and I get memory warnings. The other issue I see is that minified versions of files are throwing more errors than the un-minified version.

My question is this: Do you normally exclude the likes of jquery and bootstrap files from linting? If so, what is the point. Are there other .jshintsrc or .jscsrc files that are less restrictive or is it up to me to go through all these error by hand and either override them or modify the code. Seems completely counter productive running a tool that requires a large amount of errors to be turned off just to make some headway?

Comment: You are supposed to lint *your own code*. What's the point in linting a library like jQuery? You can't make changes to it anyway. Apart from that, their coding style doesn't necessarily match yours.

Comment: Don't lint stuff you haven't written. The output will be useless, particularly with minified files. Also I might suggest that with jQuery at least, you pull it in via google's cdn rather than having it in your own source tree.

Comment: OK, but some of the errors are in the Gulp file I wrote. As an example, move var declarations to the top of the the function .... or xyz was used before it was declared. Really? So, now I have to dig through all the documentation to find out why these errors are being thrown and find a way to switch them off. Also, why is Gulp or whatever running out of memory ? Not a good start....

Comment: I don't understand it. If you don't want to know about errors in your code, why are you running it through a static analysis tool? The whole point of jslint is to inform you of mistakes that go beyond basic syntax errors.

Comment: @Greg - Tools like JSHint/JSLint are designed to help you follow best practices and avoid common mistakes. You don't have to obey every rule, don't lint minified code, and definitely don't lint 3rd party code. The [documentation](http://jshint.com/docs/options/) lists options that you can use to configure JSHint to better fit your own coding style.

Comment: @James .. and that is what I am trying to do. I have just started running the tool and following tutorials to get up to speed with gulp, but when I get an error saying that something was used before it was defined, I have to question why that error is there but the javascript is working.

Comment: @Greg Because not every mistake you can make is a straight-out syntax error. JavaScript is flexible and many things are able to run but not all of them are smart to write. JSHint is there to help you see common mistakes, like using a variable before you define it.

Comment: It seems that this tripping point is common, based on other posts. Flexible is not the word that jumps to mind. In the real world this is equivalent to your car telling you its out of petrol when a wheel goes flat.

Comment: @Greg I have a feeling that **a)** your experience with JavaScript as a language is very limited and **b)** your perception of what these tools do and what their messages mean is skewed. That's not the best position for being judgmental. I recommend you lean back and let your agitation dissipate. It would help if you could put in one or two sentences what your expectations of these tools were in the first place.

Comment: @Tomalak .. yes, my experience with JavasScript is limited. That is why I am posting. Yes, I have read Douglas Crockfords book on Javascript. My expectations are that errors are real errors and not suggestions and that the tool does not blow away my command line with memory exception when I point it at a file that has lots of errors.

Comment: @Greg Huh? What has *that* got to do with the topic?

Comment: @Tomalak .. considering his knowledge on the bad parts of javascript, it has a lot to do with the topic

Comment: No, you are currently trying to derail this conversation into a "JavaScript is stupid" rant, and I'm not going to help you with that. Either we talk on-topic, focused and productively about JSHint or you are going to have to write a blog post about how much you dislike JS. Only one of these things can happen on this site.

Comment: @Greg As we've already stated, these tools are not designed to just find "real errors". The JS engine will do that when you actually run your code. If you're struggling to understand the reasoning behind some of the warnings such tools give you, I suggest simply Googling the message. I've spent a lot of time putting together explanations for exactly that at http://jslinterrors.com.